# How to compute combination in java? by using memoization?

Tags: java, recursion, memoization

I am learning JAVA myself and I am learning about memoization now. But i am kind of losing my way...

Does anyone has some sample code about how to compute the Combination in Java by using recursion and using memoization to accelerate the algorithm?

Like a way to compute C5,3 = 5*4*3/3*2*1 = 10? but using recursion?

Comment: Post code showing what you have tried, and where specifically you are stuck.  As is, the question is too broad.

Comment: Maybe you better search for `binomial coefficient`. Here is code http://penguin.ewu.edu/cscd320/Topic/Strategies/DynamicPgming/Binom_Memo.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets do it with an example **20 choose 5**

Since  `20 choose 5` is defined as `20! / ( 5! * (20-5)! )`

We could use `memoization` to store those factorial computations so we don't have to continually re-compute them under our recursion.

So:

```
    //STORING FACTORIAL COMPUTATIONS
    private Map<Integer,Long> factorialMap = new HashMap<Integer,Long>();


    public Long getFactorial(int number) {

        //CHECK IF I ALREADY COMPUTED THIS FACTORIAL
        Long val = factorialMap.get(number);
        if(val != null) {
            //GOT IT!
            return val;
        } else {
            //NEED TO COMPUTE!
            val = getFactorialRecursive(number);
            //STORING IT TO SAVE COMPUTATION FOR LATER
            factorialMap.put(number, val);
            return val;
        }
    }

    //RECURSIVE FUNCTION TO COMPUTE FACTORIAL
    public Long getFactorialRecursive(int number) {
        if(number < 2) {
            return 1L;
        } else {
            return number * getFactorialRecursive(number-1);
        }
    }


    //ACTUAL CALL TO "20 choose 5"
    public Long combination(int fromVal, int chooseVal) {
        return getFactorial(fromVal)/(getFactorial(chooseVal)*getFactorial(fromVal-chooseVal));
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help..I can understand it but i am really new to java. I can't actually run your code....

Comment: It was not meant as running code, but as an example

Comment: @jackhao I put it on pastebin http://pastebin.com/TMavCnb4

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `combinatoricslib` library available for free here:

http://code.google.com/p/combinatoricslib/